# Phantom file that cannot be deleted from git

Tags: git, visual-studio, unicode, visual-studio-2019

I imported a hg repo to github and now I have a file that was automatically renamed (I already committed the renamed file) that has a weird Unicode character in its name:

[image]

I can't commit the deletion though; when I do so, it just comes back! And I can't undo it either... How do I get this file out of my git repo for good?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can ask git to stop tracking that file with `git rm [filename]`

```
git rm [filename]
```

Replace the **[filename]** by actual file name. If it's nested, mention the path/to/filename.

If you can't type the file name, use `Tab` key for the autocomplete after typing a first few characters.

You can also copy the file name from rename option by going to that directory.

If you need the renamed version, rename it before `git rm`. Git will consider it as a new file.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe I forgot to mention that the file got renamed to something also matching that pattern, so I had to remove the renamed file before running `git rm` and paste it back in once I was done, so as to not lose the renamed file.

Comment: Updated the answer to make it generic & handle rename case.